# Creating a custom transport connector in mule

Tags: mule, mule-component, transport, mule-esb

I am attempting to create a custom transport in mule. I have followed the standard tutorial in mule and created the skeleton project.

Being a newcomer to mule, I am struggling to understand how to proceed from there. I would appreciate if you could help me answer the below questions:

- I am attempting to create a custom protocol transport, does this mean I have to create my own inbound/outbound endpoints?
- How to register the inbound/outbound and global endpoints?
- How to use the NamespaceHandler to register the endpoints?
- How to create transacted messages?
- Is it possible to have more than one MessageReceiver based on the type of connection selected by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Once look into the below url for developing custom connector with step-by-step procedure. And in that connector java class we can define more operations with @Processor as per the requirement.

http://www.vanrish.com/blog/2016/09/28/mulesoft-connector-devkit-coding-deployment/

Regards,
Murali